# In React, how to debug when await chain halts in the middle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

In React, my code sets a chain of animations using async-await:

```
animationFunc: () => async (next, cancel) => {
    cancel();
    await next(style1); //line #1
    await next(style2); //line #2
    ....
}
```

It somehow never reach line#2. The style stays as style1 forever.

If you want more context, here it is:

```
import { useTransition } from "react-spring";

const transitions = useTransition(items, item => item.key, {
    from: ...,
    enter: ...,
    leave: () => async (next, cancel) => {
        cancel();
        await next(style1);
        await next(style2);
        ...
    },
})
```

If you know why, that would be great. Meanwhile, I am also asking if you can tell me how to debug? How do I know the status of each async-await call?

Comment: `it somehow never reach line#2` - perhaps `next(style1);` is rejecting - you don't handle rejections, so ...

Comment: I preffer to use promises because i find the sintax easier to understand and to debug. But this is just my personal opinion.

Comment: yeah as @JaromandaX said you need to handle the error

Comment: @MichaelWallace - async/await is sugary syntax for Promises :p

Comment: I tried `try{}catch{}` around `await next(style1);` but no error is caught.

Answer (score 0):

Here, it is not recahing to #line2 may be because an error is countered in #line1 call. for debugging you can put your code in `try-catch` block and console the error in catch block. These common catch block will handle each and every await call.For instance,

```
animationFunc: () => async (next, cancel) => {
    try {
        cancel();
        await next(style1); //line #1
        await next(style2); //line #2
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log("Error is: ", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it, no error is caught.